# How can I know why the request does not bring data from the formdata

Tags: laravel, request

I have a problem to update the data in a table, I pass data from postman to my API developed in Laravel.

I have already tried several ways to do the update and it does not work with the request data, the request does not bring anything, I send it as formData.

What can I do, because the request of the post that is in the same controller works but not in the update?

```
public function update(Request $request,$id)
{   
    $data = [
        'name' => $request->name,
        'descrip' => $request->descrip,
        'amount' => $request->amount,
    ]; 
    $spent = Spending::find($id);
    $spent->update($data);
  
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'data' => $spent]);
}
```

Comment: the return of dd($request->all())   ?

Comment: return the request to check what you get from the api call. and add postman part too in the question.

Comment: return of dd($request->all()) array:1 [
  "scope" => "collector"
]

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to guarded.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

In the `Spending` model write

```php
protected $fillable = ['name', 'descrip', 'amount'];
```

Comment: thanks, if I have protected $fillable in the model, any other ideas you can think of, please